# ¿Como pasar parámetros de tipo arreglo a través de métodos?

Tags: c#, array, funciones

Tengo dos métodos uno que es cargar() el cual se encarga de pedir los valores que se van a operar y otro que se llama suma() el cual se debe encargar de hacer la a operación de suma de todos los valores del arreglo.

Aqui estan mis variables:

```
private int[] vector;
private string linea;
```

Aqui esta mi metodo Cargar:

```
    public void cargar() {
        for (int x=0;x<8;x++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor "+x);
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            vector[x] = int.Parse(linea);
            suma(vector[x]); --> Error
        }

    }
```

Aqui esta mi metodo Sumar:

```
public void suma(int[] v)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("vectores"+v[0]);
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
```

Aun no esta haciendo las operaciones ya que al pasar el valor de cargar a suma me marca error.

**El error es:**

*Tiene argumentos No validos*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es porque tu método `suma()`  esperaba un `vector` y usted le está pasando un `valor` que está referenciado a una posición `x` de su vector

```
suma(vector[x]);// le envia al método el valor de la posición x del vector
suma(vector); // le envía todo el vector
```

Tener en cuenta , si está buscando sumar los valores de su vector , la llamada del método debería hacerse fuera del `for`

```
 public void cargar() {
    for (int x=0;x<8;x++) {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor "+x);
        linea = Console.ReadLine();
        vector[x] = int.Parse(linea);
        //suma(vector[x]); not
    }
     suma(vector); //luego de llenar su vector llamar al método suma
}
```

> Por ultimo si todo está en una sola clase no es necesario enviarle parámetros a su método, podría trabajar directamente con el atributo

```
 public void suma()
    {
        int suma = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < this.vector.Length; x++)
        {
            suma += this.vector[x];
        }
       Console.WriteLine("Suma :  " + suma);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar van sin los corchetes

```
suma(vector);
```

Y para recibir en el método

```
public void suma (int[] vector)
```

Comment: Lo hice así y me dice que "El especificador de tipo matriz [] debe ir delante del nombre del parámetro"

Comment: el metodo no lo toques, dejalo como estaba, solamente al momento de pasar el arreglo le quitas los corchetes

Comment: Si no proba pasarlo por referencia public void suma (int *vector)